# Dynamic PHP website using POST arguments and recursive function

Tags: php, recursion, post, dynamic, reload

I'm creating a website using PHP for the logic part of it.

It is a **dynamic** test. A set of questions are presented to the user and depending on his answers, a new set of questions will appear, thus, the questions will always be different if the answers are different.

In the `form` of the test, I have used `POST` to get the answers of the user and the action is empty because I want the page to reload but with different arguments (`POST`) every time. I also use a recursive function that takes the ID's of the next questions to be presented and the level (set of questions) just to not get lost. This recursive function also uses the arguments in `POST` to, again, obtain the user's answers so it can get the next questions at my DB.

```
function searchTree($arrNodes, $nivel){
    $nxtQ = array(); $j=1;
    $arr=getPreguntas($arrNodes,$nivel); //arr has "question" objects
    $numPreg=count($arr);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $arrayA[$i] = treeRule($arr[$i]->idPreg); //Array[i] is the set of related rules
    }
    echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    for ($i=0; $i < $numPreg; $i++) { 
        echo $arr[$i]->pregunta .'</br>';
        insertHTML($arr[$i]->idPreg, $numPreg, $j, $nivel); //Add HTML
        $j++;
    }
    echo '</br><input type="submit" id="buttonSend'.$nivel.'" name="buttonSend'.$nivel.'" value="Enviar respuesta">';
    echo '</form>';
    $button= 'buttonSend'.$nivel;
    if(isset($_POST[$button])){ //If the user answered
        for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayA); $i++) { //arrayA has all related rules
            if(!empty($arrayA[$i])){ //At least one related rule
                $radio = 'valorRadio'.($i+1).'_'.$nivel;
                $node = 'idNode'.($i+1).'_'.$nivel;
                $answ[$i] = analize($_POST[$radio],$_POST[$node],$arrayA[$i],$i+1, $nivel); //$answ is the set of related rules which happened to be true
                if($answ[$i]!=null){
                    echo 'True related rule: '.$answ[$i].' </br> ';
                }else{
                    echo 'Answer all questions';
                }
            }else{ //End of analysis
                echo 'No related rules </br>'; 
            }
        }

        $relatedMR = getmetaRules($arrayA);
        for ($i=0, $j=0; $i < count($relatedMR); $i++) { 
            $res = analizeMR($relatedMR[$i], $arrayA);
            if($res=='1'){
                $nxtQ[$j] = getNxtQ($relatedMR[$i]); //nxtQ is the set of next questions' IDs
                $j++;
            }
        }

        if($nxtQ!=NULL){
            $_POST=array();
            $arrNodes = array();
            searchTree($nxtQ,($nivel+1));
        }else{
            echo 'End of test';
        }

    }else{
        time_sleep_until($_POST);//Wait for an answer
    }
}
```

I call this function at the beginning of my program like this:

```
searchTree(initialNodes(1),1);
```

`initialNodes()` function only enters the DB and gets the questions with level 1.

The first and second set of questions are presented (kind of) correctly (the first set of questions is always present and the second one appears under it, but that can be fixed at front-end.), however, the third one if not working anymore. The `POST` arguments are there but the  new questions and radio buttons do not appear.

[First set and POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr9Um.png)[First and second set and POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vCcc.png)[Third attempt and POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOEJ1.png)

I created an easier example of this by not using "sets of questions" but only one question each time. The first and second questions work as I previously mentioned but for the third one, the second one is replaced by the third and the third by the fourth and so on.

I don't know if my program is getting confused by the names of my HTML elements, if my recursive function is wrong or something else.